# Symphonic metal bands with very technical guitar

Tags: similar-artists, metal, symphonic-metal

When it comes to symphonic metal bands, the guitar parts aren’t usually very complex.

I know two bands which have both symphonic instruments and very technical guitars:

- Symphony X
- Angra

Failed to find any more. Do you know any?

Comment: Are you talking about Symphonic as in 'Apocalyptica', or Symphonic as in 'Dream Theater'?  Because Dream Theater doesn't play any symphonic instruments, but between the keyboards and guitar there is plenty of orchestration and, in some cases, the keyboardist replicates stringed instruments.  And their guitarist, John Petrucci, is probably one of the most respected guitarists across several genres.

Comment: Well, I would treat metal as symphonic whenever the symphonic instrumentation plays a great role. So I would consider the album "Be" by Pain of Salvation symphonic metal (but their other albums not)

Comment: Nightwish seem like such an obvious example that you might have left them out as "not very complex". [Watch Emppu's left hand.](https://youtu.be/ETvQlbs-3Dw?t=18m56s)

Comment: Not really "symphonic" but more "neoclassical", I'd recommend Sleep Terror or Blotted Science. Oh, and watch the Blotted Science videos on youtube! They score their songs to movies!

Comment: Another obvious example of neoclassical is Malmsteem. [Icarus' Dream Suite](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1Va1F1dQWo) and [Far Beyond the Sun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAsHFSrh0i8).

Comment: Manowar are not always symphonic, but when they are, they still have kick-ass guitars.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's just asking for a list. All would-be answers are equivalent.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to check Edu Falaschi (ex-Angra) project called **Almah**. Their second album, Fragile Equality, has frequent parts of symphonic/orchestration keyboards with complex guitars riffs and progressive parts.

I also recommend you to check the Swedish Operatic Metal band **Therion**, most of their albums have complex orchestrations parts mixed with Power/Melodic Metal.

A very good way to find new bands is searching on related bands from your favourite artists on Last.fm. Or even searching on YouTube for "symphonic progressive metal bands megamix", will return a plenty of good suggestions!

Comment: Just to add another approach - I have listened through every band listed as symphonic or power metal on the encyclopedia metaluum list by genre https://www.metal-archives.com/lists/orchestral

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest **Haggard** as a full symphonic band, with "Eppur si muove".

**Septicflesh** are using a lot of orchestra parts, you can try Titan, Communion and The Great Mass.

**Dark Lunacy** had a violin in Forget me Not and Devoid.

**Fleshgod Apocalypse** uses piano and various orchestration parts, I'd suggest listening to their Agony album.

Probably less symphonic than previous bands you can give a chance to old **Novembre** albums: Arte Novecento, Classica and Novembrine Waltz.
Their composition is unique, grasps a wide range of sounds, you'd probably like it.

Answer (score 4):

When it comes to technical guitars one should definitely mention Rhapsody(now renamed to Rhapsody of Fire). Give `Gargoyles, Angels Of Darkness` a try. In their older albums Luca Turilli was playing the guitars and he is very talented guitar player. The band split in 2011 and now there are two bands - Rhapsody of Fire and Luca Turilli's Rhapsody.

You may also give Gwyllion a try (e.g. `The Night Awakes`).

It is worth to also mention [Morten Veland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morten_Veland) - some of the peaces of Sirenia and his band Mortemia could also fit in what I imagine as technical guitars.

As for Nightwish I really like the band and I think some peaces(from the older era) could fit as well - for instance give their interpretation of `Crimson Tide And Deep Blue Sea` a try.

Of course we can not leave out Therion and Haggard, but they have already been mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should check the one-man-band (from Behold the Arctopus) project Direwolf:
http://www.metal-archives.com/bands/Direwolf/91376

Fist in Fetus are also technical and symphonic.

Therion, Nightwish, are symphonic, not so technical. Same thing with Haggard, Septic Flesh and Fleshgod Apocalypse, they are trully symphonic and progressive, but I wouldn't call them technical. Dream Theater, Pain of Salvation, Dark Lunacy and Novembre don't fit the "Symphonic&Technical" combo either...

Answer (score 1):

I would also add:

- Adagio
- Yngwie Malmsteen
- Blind Guardian
- Therion
- Evergrey
- Uli Jon Roth

Also David Maxim Micic's solo albums have a symphonic vibe in them although he does not belong in that genre.

Answer (score 1):

#### Direct Answer to Your Question:--

Try "A Glimpse Beyond" by Dan Mumm.

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnIQnlxhYys)

[**Warning**: Harsh, Noisy, and/or Disorienting Sound in the video link directly above.]

---

#### Other References:--

This artist has the advantage of being a professional guitar teacher with materials you can visit:--

- (http://www.danmumm.com/do-you-really-need-theory-as-a-guitarist/)
- (https://metalmethod.com/sweep-picking-secrets)

Answer (score 0):

Did anyone answer Opeth? Or Gojira? Anytime I'm in just a chill mode...these are my go to bands! Also, love some septicflesh, nightwish, and unleash the archers. Nit sure why my brain is blank right now- I know there's a few more in there.